# IP forwarding for kde connect

Tags: networking, router, android, kde

I want to forward a [KDE connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) connection from my desktop to an android phone, which are not in the same network.

KDE connect uses the Ports `1714-1764` on tcp/udp and broadcasts to find the device in the LAN. So i will need the router between the two networks not only to forward the ports with masquerading, but also to forward the broadcast packets.

I am not sure if ip rewriting is needed, as the desktop pc may be configured to reach ips in the wlan via the router with the two interfaces.

So i need to achieve:

- broadcast packets from wlan should be forwarded to lan and vice versa.
- Once the android device sees the pc, it should be able to create a connection, which is routed with masquerading to the pc.

The docs do not say much about the protocol, but i guess the udp packets are used to find the pc via broadcast and then a tcp connection is build from the android device to the pc.